# snap failing to start due to apparmor profiles

Tags: snap, 20.10, apparmor

Recently every single snap package on my Ubuntu install stopped working.

When I would try and run them in console I would get the error:

`snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks`

I've tried reinstalling snapd, snap-confine and apparmor. As well as installed the apparmor-easyprof package. None of these things fixed the issue.

After reinstalling snap I now get this error when trying to install new snaps:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "snapd" (11402) security profiles (cannot setup profiles for snap "snapd": cannot create host snap-confine apparmor configuration: cannot reload snap-confine apparmor profile: cannot load apparmor profiles: exit status 1
apparmor_parser output:
Found reference to variable multiarch, but is never declared)
```

When I try and check apparmor's status with `aa-status` the only output is `apparmor module is loaded.` when there should be a lot more profiles being loaded and visible in the status, as far as I can tell.

The output of `systemctl status apparmor` is:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-30 18:51:05 EDT; 34min ago
       Docs: man:apparmor(7)
             https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home/
   Main PID: 10619 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop apparmor.systemd[10754]: Found reference to variable HOMEDIRS, but is never declared
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop apparmor.systemd[10762]: Warning: found usr.sbin.sssd in /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain, forcing complain mode
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop apparmor.systemd[10762]: Found reference to variable multiarch, but is never declared
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop apparmor.systemd[10758]: Found reference to variable multiarch, but is never declared
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop apparmor.systemd[10764]: Found reference to variable HOME, but is never declared
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop apparmor.systemd[10765]: Found reference to variable PROC, but is never declared
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop apparmor.systemd[10619]: Error: At least one profile failed to load
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 30 18:51:05 samp-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
```

Comment: I'm currently looking into AppArmor to solve this issue for Kali and `sudo apparmor_status --verbose` doesn't show any profiles for snapd until they are loaded in manually with `sudo apparmor_parser /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*`.

For Discord, I the minimum number of files needed to be loaded are:
```zsh
sudo apparmor_parser /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.discord
sudo apparmor_parser /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.discord.discord
sudo apparmor_parser /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.snapd.14066
```

Comment: I don't know if this'll work for Ubuntu, so I won't post as an answer, but it worked for me on Kali. Open `/lib/apparmor/rc.apparmor.functions` and look for the line `ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_DIR=` and paste your snapd profile directory into that line. For me, the profile directory was `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/`.

Comment: @AlexisEvelyn works well on Ubuntu 20.02.2