# How to configure AppArmor for Snaps?

Tags: 20.04, snap, apparmor

I've been using Snaps such as `telegram-desktop` and `caprine` for some time. `caprine` worked for a few days, but then AppArmor started to show denials in `dmesg`. `caprine` didn't even start, just crashed when I tried to launch it. So, I uninstalled it and installed a deb package of `caprine`, which works fine.

`telegram` started to have issues too. I can't download/upload files. It just shows "Failed" whenever I try to download/upload something. I looked at my `dmesg`, and here's what was there:

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1618899013.777:481): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" ...
```

It seems Snaps don't have AppArmor properly configured. Is there a way to configure this? I had a similar situation with MySQL, where I edited some files and allowed specific paths. How is this done with Snaps?

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with the Brave browser from snap. It was being blocked from preventing the screen saver from kicking in, so streaming was constantly interrupted. I found the problem to be a couple of things: First, the apparmor policy for all snaps is very restrictive, and second, the profiles provided for individual snap applications aren't picked up automatically.

To start, do what Alexis Evelyn suggests [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328287/snap-failing-to-start-due-to-apparmor-profiles):
Open /lib/apparmor/rc.apparmor.functions and look for the line ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_DIR= and paste your snapd profile directory into that line. For me, the profile directory was /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/

Then open up the apparmor profile for the program affected for editing (using sudo), like snap.brave.brave. Some of these are very long, so look for a place that seems appropriate, or just scroll to the end (before the closing curly brace) and add a block similar to this, but with the info from your syslog error:

```
dbus (send)
    bus=session
    interface=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit
    path=/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit
    member=Inhibit
    peer=(label=unconfined),
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_DIR advice seems out dated, at least for Ubuntu 22.04.1 when I do `sudo apparmor_status --verbose` I see all the snap generated profiles from `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/` listed there.